# Why does this code not display the correct answer to the calculation and why does it loop infinitely??

Tags: c++

> I am trying to use the calculations to separate the numbers and then square them and then add
>   them together. So 79 would become 7 and 9. Then I want it to square 7 and 9 and add the results. 
>   And do it all over again until I have 50 results or the result becomes 1. Also it loops
>   infinitely. Any ideas??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{   
int number = 79;
int newNumber1;
int newNumber2;
int digit1;
int digit2;
int count;
int counter = 1;

 while(number != 1 && counter != 50)
 {
    for(count = 1; count <= 10; count++)
    {
        cout << setw(8) << number;
        counter++;
        digit1 = number / 10;
        digit2 = number % 10;
        newNumber1 = pow(digit1 , 2);
        newNumber2 = pow(digit2 , 2);
        number = newNumber1 + newNumber2;
    }
  }
   cout << endl << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would be a great opportunity to learn to use a debugger to step by your code line-by-line and see if the values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Is it not a problem that `7² + 9²` has more digits than you seem to be expecting -- two?

Answer (score 3):

The inner `for` loop will run 10 times per each of the outer loop iterations. This means that at the first outer loop iteration it `counter` will be `1`, the second `11`, the third `21`, the fourth `31`, the fifth `41` and the sixth `51`; therefore the condition `counter != 50` should really be `counter < 50`.

The logic behind `number` seems also flawed somehow. In the first iteration `newNumber1 = 49` and `newNumber2 = 81` so you have `number = 49 + 81 = 130`. Now the next iteration you have `newNumber1 = 13 ^ 2` and `newNumber2 = 0`. So this number seems to always increase.
`number = 1` will happen only when you have `newNumber1 = 1` and `newNumber2 = 0` or viceversa. This happens only when you have either `digit1` or `digit2` that are `= 1`. This only happens when `number = 10`, but `number = 10` seems to never happen. So the condition `number != 1` doesn't mean much.